# Online publication system for a journal

Tags: journals, website, online-publication

I'm looking for solutions to help modernizing the publication of a scientific journal on the web. Since 2004 we are using a simple but cumbersome method of publication, by crafting html/css files from templates, with a bit of php/mysql to maintain the authors' database. We now have the opportunity (time and server access) to upgrade the hosting software system.

We (extensively) tried [OpenJournalSystems](https://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/), but it's too comprehensive and cumbersome for us, we have a simpler paper review and publication process. I haven't found [any other solution like OJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Publication_management_software) that's also free and open source (the journal is open access).

As of today, I'm envisaging two types of solutions :

- a classic CMS (like wordpress) with a "journal" theme (like [Annotum](http://annotum.org/) ?)
- a handmade PHP/MySQL system using a PHP Framework (CakePHP, CodeIgniter, ...).

Anyone has some experience to share ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the *OpenJournalSystems* (OJS) software, I'm aware of the following **free and open source solutions** that you might want to consider. They are similar to OJS in terms of functionality, but, perhaps, simpler:

- [DPubS (Digital Publishing System)](http://dpubs.org);
- [EPrints](http://www.eprints.org/software).

While I would strongly prefer *open source software*, just for completeness, below I will mention some *commercial hosted solution*s:

- [Atypon's Literatum](https://www.atypon.com/products/literatum);
- [bepress' Digital Commons](http://digitalcommons.bepress.com/repository-software/journals).

Finally, a few words on **alternative solutions** that you consider. In my opinion, the *CMS solution* is feasible, but, you will likely to lose some features found in specialized open source solutions, such as *DPubS* or *EPrints*, for example, *document workflow*, *flexible user rights management* and more. I would be very cautious about and, actually, don't recommend the handmade MySQL/PHP system (or any other *handmade solution*, for that matter) due to various reasons, including, but not limited to, **significant efforts** required for *creation and maintenance* of such system.

Comment: Thanks for your input. DPubs and EPrints seems to be complex and not very recent solutions. I think i'll focus my search on the web publication aspects instead of the paper reviewing workflow. I've found some pointers on this post : http://www.openoasis.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=353:tools-and-platforms&catid=80:articles&Itemid=379

Comment: @LaurentJégou: You're welcome and good luck! The post you referred to is indeed interesting.